# How to embed a Facebook Page's public info (like count) to a website using Graph API v2?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My previous implementation of using GET request to url https://graph.facebook.com/538726722826117 is broken now that Facebook has moved to Graph API v2 and requires an auth token for fetching this information. And as it is a website, I cannot embed a token which would have any more access rights than for reading a page's public information.

How to implement this rather simple task of getting a page's public **like** and **check-ins count**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to autorize, you can just use an App Access Token for the API call. Of course you should not use the Token on the client, but it´s perfectly fine to use it on the server. Make the API call with `file_get_contents` or `curl` - that is, if you are using PHP.

An App Access Token is very simple, it´s just the App ID and the App Secret, combined with a pipe sign: `App-ID|App-Secret`

More information about Tokens for the Facebook API:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: I would prefer doing it just with JavaScript. But if there is no other way (?) then yes I can do it with PHP.

Another thing was that I was using Facebook Graph Explorer I was not able to find the proper query syntax for accessing the page's information (except querying with ID gave only ID and name back). Is the some documentation page which would list all the possible objects/keys for a Page?

Comment: no, you should not use tokens on the client. about the information, please check out the changelog and search for "declarative fields" - and the api reference to find all the possible fields.

Comment: _“Is the some documentation page which would list all the possible objects/keys for a Page?”_ – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page Plus you can also append a GET parameter to a specific request, to see what fields are available, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#introspection